# DAYNAME(CURDATE())

Tags: mysql

Нужно добавить колонку, в которую при добавлении строки записывалось бы имя текущего дня недели. Пробовал с несколькими типами и ставил значение по умолчанию `DAYNAME(CURDATE())`, не получилось. Примерно как реализовано здесь со временем

```
`add_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Зачем? Оставьте `add_time DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, а день недели получайте в запросе, используя функцию.

Comment: @Akina `add_time` остается. необходимо добавить новое поле, к уже существующим

Comment: Это называется "переопределённые данные" - когда хранимое значение можно рассчитать на основании других значений. И всяческим образом порицается, если к тому нет совершенно убойных обоснований. У Вас - нет, или по крайней мере пока не озвучено. А потому добавление поля дня недели, хотя его значение легко считается в запросе - ошибочное решение. Пока не поздно - откажитесь. Во избежание проблем рассогласования данных в будущем.

Comment: @Akina есть запрос, который определенным образом получает данные за прошлую неделю, делаются определенные расчеты и выводятся пользователю. В течении недели показатели меняются. Данные сохраняются каждый день. Есть необходимость рядом с расчетными колонками, выводить колонки с разницей между текущим и "топовым" аналогичным днем недели. Мне показалось,проще делать это,дописывая в строку день недели. Готов выслушать замечания и предложения.

Comment: Ваше объяснение - это доказательство того, что переопределение данных в Вашем случае ничем не обосновано. Предложение уже озвучено - получать день недели в момент, когда его значение требуется. Выражением в запросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте триггером:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_name` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name`
 FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.`field_name` IS NULL
  THEN
    SET NEW.`field_name` = DAYNAME(CURDATE());
  END IF;
```